Using while (not when) with perfect continuous tenses
I have asked many questions about "when" and past perfect and how to combine them. You gave me many examples and tips. Still, I asked you questions about "when". Now I want to check if it is possible to use "while" with perfect tenses. I feel that it can't be done but I want to make sure.

While you have been boiling potatoes "for 6 minutes", check if they are soft"

I just don't know if "while" is fine in my sentence maybe without time expression but with one it sounds just wrong but I don't know why and if my impression is right?

Not my downvote, but no. After you have boiled the potatoes for six minutes, ... while is used with ongoing actions not actions that have completed or achieved a desired duration.

I've edited the title to reflect that you've used the perfect continuous, not simply the perfect.

Surely, for cooking, we'd say "after x time, check y".

While the potatoes've have been boiling, we've been drinking wine. I am pretty sure that in your native language, the sample sentence would not work.

While you have been boiling potatoes is Present Perfect, not Past Perfect.

while is not used with achieved states.
This is OK because it is an ongoing action, not an achieved state:

While the tea has been steeping, ...

But this next usage is not OK because "has steeped for a full three minutes" refers to an achieved state:

While the tea has steeped for a full three minutes, add ... ungrammatical

POP QUIZ:
Grammatical or ungrammatical?

While the first coat of paint has dried, give it a light sanding with fine-grit sandpaper and then put on another coat.


it is a stupid sentence but I want to see if "while" could work there. "While he has been cleaning the kitchen I join to help". Let's it is a repeated occurance. Will "while" work here

Given example is wrong

"While he has been cleaning the kitchen I join to help" is not an idiomatic English utterance.   There are a number of things at odds with each other in that utterance, so many that I hardly know where to begin.  The matrix clause should mirror the verb form in the subordinate clause:  While he has been cleaning the kitchen, I have been mowing the lawn.

@user203412 While he has been cleaning the kitchen refers to a duration of time that has already happened, so you cannot have present tense "I join" in the matrix clause.  And that is the case whether the kitchen-cleaning is a one-time thing or a habitual task.

Also, do not be led astray by the concessive use of while, where it is a synonym for although.    E.g. While has has been cleaning the kitchen, I have been joining in to help. He has not had to do all the work himself.  In such cases where while means although, you might find something like this: While (although) he has been cleaning the kitchen, I do join in to help.

you made this all clear. Thank you very much.

While doesn't work in your example sentence, because you would test the potatoes when (after) you have boiled them for a certain length of time, not at some random point during the cooking.
However, it would be perfectly OK to say to someone who has come in from working in the garden;

While you have been mowing the lawn, I have been making you a nice lunch.

(The two activities were taking place at the same time.)

it is a stupid sentence but I want to see if "while" could work there. "While he has been cleaning the kitchen I join to help". Let's it is a repeated occurance. Will "while" work here

"I join" requires "While he is cleaning the kitchen".
